# ROLLUP e HAVING na mesma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

A consulta abaixo retorna a soma de **24 contas**, usando o `ROLLUP` e sem a cláusula `HAVING`, até aí tudo bem, porém quando eu uso a cláusula `HAVING` logo depois do `ROLLUP` deveria me retornar a soma de 19 contas, mas continua me retornando a soma de 24 contas. Como eu faço para que o `ROLLUP` me traga a soma certa, independentemente de qualquer condição `HAVING`?

**Consulta sem a cláusula `HAVING`**

```
SELECT 
 ifnull(cust_id, 'Total') as ID_cliente,
 count(account_id) as QTDE_de_contas
 FROM account
 GROUP BY
 cust_id WITH ROLLUP
```

**Consulta com a cláusula `HAVING`**

```
SELECT 
 ifnull(cust_id, 'Total') as ID_cliente,
 count(account_id) as QTDE_de_contas
 FROM account
 GROUP BY
 cust_id WITH ROLLUP
 HAVING
 count(account_id) >= 2
```

Comment: *"Como eu faço para que o ROLLUP me traga a soma certa, independentemente de qualquer condição HAVING"* isso não faz sentido, o `rollup` é baseado no `group by`, que é filtrado pelo `having`, são coisas totalmente dependentes, se não quer o `having` precisa remover da query... seria como fazer um select e querer que os resultados não dependam no `where`

Comment: Olá Ricardo, acredito que eu não me fiz entender, quando eu executo a query sem o `HAVING`, a query me traz um valor, porém quando eu uso o filtro `HAVING`, a query continua me trazendo o mesmo valor e não deveria. Foi isso que eu quis dizer.